# Spring JPA + Boot - Single Character Value not returning

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANGED_NAME")
public class IDSUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "SSO_NUMBER")
    private String userId;

    @Column (name = "OPER_SHIFT")
    private String operShift;

// Getter Setter Methods
}
```

Spring JPA Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRespository extends CrudRepository<IDSUser, String>  {

    public List<IDSUser> findByOperShift(String operShift);

}
```

// Here if i try to search using opershift as "Test" -- it works.
But when i pass the value as only "A" or "B" (Single Character) it does not work.

Can someone tell me, if i am doing something wrong here?
When i run with more than one character, the query works in JPA. But with single character it does not work. When i try in sql developer with single character, the query is working.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen? Is there actually a entity with value `A` for `operShift`? It is an exact match not a `like`.

Comment: The table has the value with 'A' as the character. But it does not fetch it.

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: In tthe database its Char(3). Have tried giving the length in the column in the Entity class. That also did not help.

Comment: if it is char `A` won't match it is `A  ` that matches. `CHAR` is a fixed length as opposed to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Hi, when i pass the value A with spaces, it works. But is there any alternative for this. I mean , then each time, i will need to add the spaces for this kind of data to fetch it.

Comment: That is due to the fact that it is a `char` column in the database. You would have to append it to the length of the column with spaces (or change the column to a `varchar` in the database.

Comment: Since , it was a legacy database and i cant change the char to varchar. So, i had to convert the parameters by myself to do the query. e.g. select * from test_emp where emp_name = ? to select * from test_emp where emp_name = 'Test'.  This way it does not have the problem of the char. It just directly fires the query and get back the results.

Comment: It still has the same problem, if it doesn't match the length of the char it still fails.